# JQuery Autocomplete didn't work when using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I want to make an autocomplete text field to display the name and get the value when i select one of them.

Im following the tutorial from this site

[here](http://cdn.rawgit.com/salmanarshad2000/demos/v1.0.0/jquery-ui-autocomplete/using-label-value-pairs.html)

and success. the working code is like this:

```
var data = [
        { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
        { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
        { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" }
];
$(function() {
        $("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to replace the var data written above with my JSON.
here is what my JSON look like

```
[{"value":"1","label":"Gambir"},{"value":"2","label":"Kebon Kelapa"},{"value":"3","label":"Petojo Utara"}]
```

i want to do this

```
var data = [
        here would be data from my json,
        the JSON url: app.base_url+'adm/pengiriman/pengiriman_kodepos'
        how to write code to retrieve JSON in here?
];
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

but, what is the proper way to do that?
i try modify the source from this:

```
source: data,
```

become this:

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON(app.base_url+'adm/pengiriman/pengiriman_kodepos', function (data) {
         response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
             return {
                 label: value,
                 value: key
             };
          }));
     });
},
```

or this:

```
source: function(request, response) {
              $.ajax({
                url: app.base_url+'adm/pengiriman/pengiriman_kodepos',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { q: request.term },
                success: function(data) {
                  response($.map(data, function(value,key) {
                    return { label:value.label , value: value.value }
                  }));
                }
              });
            },
```

or this:

```
source: app.base_url+'adm/pengiriman/pengiriman_kodepos',
```

still have no luck.. im pretty new to JQuery and also JSON
thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ajax request in asynchronous, so you have to use a callback and create the autocomplete ui in that. Please see the code below. Not tested, so you may have to tweak the code, but this is how it can be done.

```
function getData(responseCallback) {
  $.getJSON(app.base_url + 'adm/pengiriman/pengiriman_kodepos', function(data) {
    responseCallback(data);
  });
}


function createAutocomplete(data) {
  $("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
    source: data,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
      $("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
    }
  });
}

getData(createAutocomplete);
```

I have created an example here : https://jsbin.com/subihohuje/1/edit?html,output

It gets data from : https://jsonblob.com/api/9ae66445-f11b-11e6-901d-295e753a8fe1

Comment: thanks for replying. I try that code, did't work yet and no error.. 
and what do you mean by tweak the code?

is that any possible way to get a JSON array and put it to replace the code

    var data = [
        { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
        { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
        { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" }
];

Comment: If you can create a `jsbin` or `jsfiddle` it can be quickly resolved.

Comment: You can't directly replace `data` with json as requests to made to server is asynchronous.

Comment: here is my jsfiddle with working example, without json..
https://jsfiddle.net/m5za8oz5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean.
Just replace the json with your json

Comment: thats what i really want to do. replace the var data = [
        { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
        { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
        { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" }
];
with my json from the url:

app.base_url+'adm/pengiriman/pengiriman_kodepos'

i'll keep trying